# Problemas com rotas no ASP .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Olá, possuo a seguinte rota:

```
routes.MapRoute("RelatorioDemonstrativoResultadoExercicio", "downloads/relatorios/Relatorio_DRE_{dataInicio}_{dataTermino}.pdf", new { controller = "RelatorioFinanceiro", action = "DemonstrativoResultadoExercicio" });
```

Uso ela para criar um PDF e baixar para o cliente. 
O problema é que ela parou de funcionar. Atualizei o MVC e simplismente parou.
Ele não localiza mais o controller nem nada.
Porém, se eu fizer assim:

```
routes.MapRoute("RelatorioDemonstrativoResultadoExercicio", "downloads/relatorios/Relatorio_DRE/{dataInicio}/{dataTermino}", new { controller = "RelatorioFinanceiro", action = "DemonstrativoResultadoExercicio" });
```

ela volta a funcionar.
Alguém sabe o que aconteceu? O que devo fazer para a minha rota antiga funcionar?
Segue abaixo o Controller que deveria ser acionado:

```
public void DemonstrativoResultadoExercicio(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataTermino)
    {
        dataInicio = dataInicio.Date;
        dataTermino = new DateTime(dataTermino.Year, dataTermino.Month, dataTermino.Day, 23, 59, 59);

        BancoDadosBO db = new BancoDadosBO();
        RelatorioFinanceiroCO.DemonstrativoResultadoExercicio(Response.OutputStream, db, idContaSistema, idUsuario, dataInicio, dataTermino);
        db.Commit();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Se bem percebi a única diferença nas duas rotas é o `.pdf`, certo? Será que não estás a colocar a `dataTermino` com o `.pdf`? Ou que estás a adicionar na tua action?

Comment: Ao debugar seu *controller*, você consegue pelo menos parar dentro da Action? Se sim, os parâmetros estão preenchidos corretamente?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, ele nem chega a parar no controller

Comment: @CesarMiguel, não cheguei a testar a rota sem o .PDF, mas o estranho é que antes, em MVC3, ela funcionava.

Comment: P.s: Adicionei o Controller na pergunta.